# Multi select values options jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to create a job where I have to select multiple values for one parameter.
env: dev1, dev2, qa1, qa2 etc
I want to be able to select dev1 & dev2 to update certain values.
Is there a way/plugin for Jenkins to handle it?

Comment: Did you try the suggestion?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

[Extended Choice Parameter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin) plugin is the way to go for such requirement. You need to select `Extended Choice Parameter` from the drop-down list as shown below:

[image]

In `Name` text-box, assign a name. For example, *Environment*. This is the name with which you will be accessing all the values (dev1,dev2,...) that you will select while triggering the build. Now, in `Simple Parameter Types` section, you will see another drop-down with the name `Parameter Type`. Select `Multi Select` from that drop-down. Now, in `Choose Source for Value` section, enter the values (dev1,dev2,qa1,qa2,...) in `Value` box. Comma (,) is the default delimiter. Refer screenshot below:

[image]

Once you are done with the above settings, you will then have to access the selected option in your script (using variable assigned to `Name` as described above) and decide the course of action.

Comment: Finally i got a reply. ;) I'm glad it worked. It's good to accept the answer so that others who visit this page know that the OP's (Original Poster) query was resolved with my answer.

Comment: Sorry @VaibhavJain. I didn't get chance to work on Jenkins after version 1.0 so i cannot comment on it.

Comment: How are the selected parameters sent to my java program? Will they be delimited too?

Comment: @VaibhavJain you'll need to look into implementing something like this - https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/219555588-Create-drop-down-list-selection-of-files-populated-from-git-repository-in-Pipeline

Comment: How do we access the "values" in jenkins pipeline ?? like "Name.Value" ?? is this by default List<String> ??

Comment: @Prathameshdhanawade, if the parameter name is "Name", use `params.Name` to access the value. From my limited testing it looks like it returns a String, so you'll have to `split(',')` to extract multiple values. YMMV.

Comment: Openin the plugin webpage screams in red

Answer (score 1):

Since [Extended Choice Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/extended-choice-parameter/) plugin has now security issues, I would suggest [Active Choices](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) instead, using for example a simple checkbox configuration.
For your example, you would add an "Active Choices Parameter", select "Groovy Script" and add the possible values (mark as *selected* the ones you want selected by default):

[image: values for active choices parameter]

Then you only need to choose the style you want for the rendering, like check boxes:

[image: render parameter as check boxes]

The result:

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate. This answer only mentions the tools to use, but not how to use them. So for now this is a link-only answer and could have been posted as a comment instead.