# How to pass multi select value parameter in Jenkins file(Groovy)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

E.g. Below code is used for single select value

```
        choice{
           choices: 'Box\nOneDrive\nSharePointOnline\nGmail\nGDrive\nGenericS3',
           defaultValue: 'box', 
           description:  'Connector to build',
           name: 'On_Cloud_Devices_To_Test'
         }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multi select values options jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26006265/multi-select-values-options-jenkins)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would use booleanParam's. Then the user can tick all the required options.

```
booleanParam(defaultValue: false, name: 'ALL', description: 'Process all'),
booleanParam(defaultValue: false, name: 'OPTION_1', description: 'Process option 1'),
booleanParam(defaultValue: false, name: 'OPTION_2', description: 'Process options 2'),
```

Comment: `booleanParam('RUN_TESTS', true, 'uncheck to disable tests')`
this works for me https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/pipelineJob-parameters-booleanParam

Comment: Using this approach, what does the rest of the script look like to run stages for each selected parameter?

Comment: @MrPablo You would use conditionals, so If ALL or OPTION_X then { do thing }, if ALL or OPTION_Y then { do otherthing }

Answer (score 11):

You could use "Extended Choice Parameter" plugin, as [this page](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003895271-How-to-do-a-multiselect-input-in-a-pipeline) suggests.

Sinse the parameter list is very long, you may wrap it into a function:

```
import com.cwctravel.hudson.plugins.extended_choice_parameter.ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition

def checkBox (String name, String values, String defaultValue,
              int visibleItemCnt=0, String description='', String delimiter=',') {

    // default same as number of values
    visibleItemCnt = visibleItemCnt ?: values.split(',').size()
    return new ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition(
            name, //name,
            "PT_CHECKBOX", //type
            values, //value
            "", //projectName
            "", //propertyFile
            "", //groovyScript
            "", //groovyScriptFile
            "", //bindings
            "", //groovyClasspath
            "", //propertyKey
            defaultValue, //defaultValue
            "", //defaultPropertyFile
            "", //defaultGroovyScript
            "", //defaultGroovyScriptFile
            "", //defaultBindings
            "", //defaultGroovyClasspath
            "", //defaultPropertyKey
            "", //descriptionPropertyValue
            "", //descriptionPropertyFile
            "", //descriptionGroovyScript
            "", //descriptionGroovyScriptFile
            "", //descriptionBindings
            "", //descriptionGroovyClasspath
            "", //descriptionPropertyKey
            "", //javascriptFile
            "", //javascript
            false, //saveJSONParameterToFile
            false, //quoteValue
            visibleItemCnt, //visibleItemCount
            description, //description
            delimiter //multiSelectDelimiter
            )
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
def testParam = checkBox("opt", // name
                "opt1,opt2,opt3", // values
                "opt1", //default value
                0, //visible item cnt
                "Multi-select", // description
                )

properties(
  [parameters([testParam])]
)

node {
    echo "${params.opt}"
}
```

Jenkins Build with Parameters:

[image]

This is scripted pipeline syntax by the way.