# Extended Choice Parameter implementation

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm setting up a new job in which we are required to select Multiple values. Need to select Service1 and Service2...
Went through link [How to pass multi select value parameter in Jenkins file(Groovy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48898928/how-to-pass-multi-select-value-parameter-in-jenkins-filegroovy)
However, I am not sure how to pass values in my Jenkinsfile

A snippet of Jenkinsfile

```
stage('parallel'){

                parallel( 

                    "service1": {stage('service1-deployment') {
                     if (params.ServiceName == 'Service1' || params.ServiceName == 'ALL'){  
                        b = build(job: 'job name', parameters: [string(name: 'ENVIRONMENT', value: TARGET_ENVIRONMENT),string(name: 'IMAGE_TAG', value: value)], propagate: false).result
                        if(b=='FAILURE'){
                                echo "job failed"
                                currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'
                            }
                    }       
                }
            },  



                "service2": {stage('service2t') {
                     if (params.ServiceName == 'service2' || params.ServiceName == 'ALL'){  
                        b = build(job: 'Job name', parameters: [string(name: 'ENVIRONMENT', value: TARGET_ENVIRONMENT),string(name: 'IMAGE_TAG', value: value)], propagate: false).result
                        if(b=='FAILURE'){
                                echo "job failed"
                                currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'
                            }
                    }       
                }   
            },
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you're using [declarative pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-pipeline) syntax for your job.

So, if the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48962320/10721592) for [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48898928/how-to-pass-multi-select-value-parameter-in-jenkins-filegroovy) with `booleanParam` is useful for you, then you can use it inside `parameters` section (see the official [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters) for more details):

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {

        booleanParam(defaultValue: false, name: 'ALL', description: 'Process all'),
        booleanParam(defaultValue: false, name: 'OPTION_1', description: 'Process option 1'),
        booleanParam(defaultValue: false, name: 'OPTION_2', description: 'Process options 2'),

    }
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                echo "All: ${params.ALL}"

                echo "Option 1: ${params.OPTION_1}"

                echo "Option 2: ${params.OPTION_2}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, if you want to use extended choice parameter with multiselect input, you need to use [scripted pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#scripted-pipeline) syntax, see [this](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003895271-How-to-do-a-multiselect-input-in-a-pipeline) example (already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52092261/10721592)).