# Jenkins run job sometimes one parameter, sometimes multiple times for all parameters

Tags: java, jenkins

I'm very new to Jenkins so I'm not sure if this is possible or not.

I need to create a job that has a parameter choice drop down menu.

My problem is that sometimes we need to do the job for all the parameters and it's not efficient to repeat the execution for every one of the parameters so I want to add a parameter that is called `all` and when it's chosen the job will execute for every parameter in the drop down menu.

Is it possible to do that?

Hopefully you understand what I mean.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to S.O!! What is your functional requirement? Maybe your drop down menu is not the best approach.

Comment: This might not match exactly, but there's a plugin called the "Extended Choice Plugin" you can install and then have a multi-select. So the user could just select all the parameters. See this SO post that might be helpful: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26006265/multi-select-values-options-jenkins)

Comment: If your choices in drop down are static i.e. you enter them manually as opposed to dynamically populating using a groovy script then you can simply instruct your pipeline to iterate over all your parameters when ‘All’ is selected in the drop down menu. Hard code all the parameters as a list in your pipeline and iterate.

Comment: If dynamically populating the choices using a groovy script then you have to configure your pipeline in such a way that when ‘All’ is selected in drop down you run the same script in your pipeline assign the values to a list and iterate. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks everyone! at the end I just used the Extended Choice Plugin and the multi select option :)

Answer (score 1):

Pipeline choices parameter is your best bet BUT at the time of writing choices does not support setting values dynamically from the result of some function.

You CAN have a static list and include `all` as an option.